# kendoSlider increase/decrease button size

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to decrease the size of the buttons on the kendoSlider (for that matter, the slider is also too large).

Their [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/slider) doesn't really make any mention of it.

Why do I want to do this? I've recently added it to my footer and the buttons are so big that it's bumped up the size of my footer entirely. I'd rather decrease the button size instead of completely changing the size of my footer.

I would assume it's something with the CSS for the slider, but I haven't had any luck with that so far.

Here's an image to demonstrate what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the Buttons to big, why just hide them?

With

```
 showButtons: false
```

in the configuration.

The size of the Buttons you can change via css. For example:

```
.k-slider .k-button, .k-grid .k-slider .k-button {
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    /* new */
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.k-slider .k-button .k-icon {
    margin-top: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Inspect the HTML element with chrome devtools or firefox.

I think the "size" of the slider you can adjust with this class:

```
.k-slider-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

For the sprite-size eventually [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) helps out.
Or just creatte your own one.

Comment: This does indeed decrease the size of the buttons, but the slider div  is still too large.

Comment: Try this: <input id="slider" type="range" style="width:50px;" />

Comment: Why would that change the height of the div...?

Comment: I'm also still left with the actual arrow sprites being too big.

Comment: This will of course only change the width. The slider is "too large" is a bit unclear.

Comment: What's unclear? Look at the screenshot. It's too big in comparison to the rest of the icons on the footer.